# funcion mostrar valor de seleccion radio, conflicto entre varios grupos radio

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo tres grupos radio . y una función para mostrar el valor del seleccionado, la misma funcion respectiva para cada uno asociada al id del grupo radio. Para ser claro cree un archivo jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c5q3touf/#&togetherjs=82FlEvSA2b

Al mostrar el valor del input seleccionado de determinado grupo, se muestra el que ha sido seleccionado del primer grupo superior , que ya tenga alguna selección, son tres filas. Si se empieza de la fila de abajo, sale bien, pero una vez se seleccionó una superior, al cambiar la selección del grupo inferior, se muestra el valor del primer grupo que tenga selección.

se puede probar en el archivo con el link. 
Agradezco su interés. 
Saludos

Comment: Lo siento, el enlace no funciona, muestra una página en blanco cuando le doy a ejecutar. ¿Podrías arreglarlo?

Comment: Hola. Ya puse el enlace para compartir   . Gracias

Comment: El problema, @Hernan527, es que en tu ejemplo estás usando rutas relativas a archivos que no tenemos, por lo que nada funciona para poder probarlo. Por ejemplo, se intenta cargar jQuery desde la ruta `floating-j-menu/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`.

Comment: Hola. Ya elimine todo lo ajeno al caso. Gracias

Comment: Ya lo tienes amigo, miralo ahora

Answer (score 0):

En princio tienes bien una parte, pero lo que hacias al declarar la `var $radChecked` era esto `$(':radio:checked');`, con eso estas llamando a todos los radios del body, y no del div donde estan ubicados, te he corregido el error, en si es la linea donde declaras `var $radChecked`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $radBtn = $("#odontologia");
            $radBtn.click(function() {
                var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked');
                $("#forro").text('')
                    .append($radChecked.val());
            });
        });
        $(function() {
            var $radBtn = $("#optica");
            $radBtn.click(function() {
                var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked');
                $("#grito").text('')
                    .append($radChecked.val());
            });
        });
        $(function() {
            var $radBtn = $("#reintegros");
            $radBtn.click(function() {
                var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked');
                $("#para").text('')
                    .append($radChecked.val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Gracias, un espectáculo. Disculpame los términos que utilicé para reemplazar #para . Quedaron de mis pruebas